# Error compiling Realtek rtl8723be drivers for Solus

Tags: drivers, realtek

I want to compile Realtek rtl8723be drivers for Solus. I have found this git repo which contains the driver:
https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new

I am trying to follow these steps:

```
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
```

I get this output after running 'make':

```
$ make
make -C /lib/modules/4.16.7-66.current/build M=/home/priten/rtlwifi_new modules

make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.16.7-66.current'
Makefile:974: *** "Cannot generate ORC metadata for CONFIG_UNWINDER_ORC=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel".  Stop.

make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.16.7-66.current'
make: *** [Makefile:58: all] Error 2
```

Comment: I already have quoted that post in my question. I just joined this forum and it won't let me add a comment on that post, if I don't have at least 50 points. That is why I had to open this question.

Comment: Have you tried installing the libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel packages mentioned in the error message? The package name might be different on the distribution you are using.

Comment: The error message clearly states the problem. You haven't installed the required packages. Install them and run make again. There is no need to change the makefile.

Comment: I am running Solus, and I tried to find the mentioned packages but I could not find it.

Comment: Search for their source code and compile them manually.

Comment: To compile the source code I will need `make`. It is a recursive dependency.

Comment: I tried to compile the elfutils source code, as explained on this site:
http://nanxiao.me/en/build-elfutils-libelf-from-source-code/

While running ./configure I am getting this error:
configure: WARNING: "libc does not have argp"
checking for argp_parse in -largp... no
configure: error: **"no libargp found"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, here's what I did to resolve this issue:

## Install necessary libraries

```
sudo eopkg up
sudo eopkg install -c system.devel
sudo eopkg it linux-current-headers
# OR, depending on your kernel
sudo eopkg it linux-lts-headers
sudo eopkg it libelf-devel
```

## Compile Realtek WiFi driver

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new
cd rtlwifi_new/
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2
sudo ip link set wlo1 up
sudo iw dev wlo1 scan
sudo su
sudo echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2" > /etc/modprobe.d/50-rtl8723be.conf
exit
```